# Can I use transaction logs to rebuild a database?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, transaction

We've had some data loss and don't have a reliable backup it seems. We do have HUGE transaction logs and there was some thought that we might be able to use these to get back to a certain point.

Is it possible to help rebuild a database using transaction logs?

SQL Server 2008 R2, btw.

(x-posted from stackoverflow)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. You need a previous image of the a database (ie. a reliable backup) to start from.

Comment: It looks like we found a .bak file from July.  Not ideal, but it's something.

Answer (score 6):

As [Remus Rusanu said](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7359/can-i-use-transaction-logs-to-rebuild-a-database/7362#7362), you cannot rebuild the database. It's bad, but it's true. But the data from your log can be extracted by tools like Lumigent LogExplorer. I understand, that it is very litle possiblity that it can help, but maybe this is the way to extract something that you need.

Comment: +1 There are some [incredible tales of recovery from impossible situations](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Unbelievable-tale-of-disaster-and-recovery.aspx). A percentage of the data may indeed be recoverable, if it has sufficient value to warrant the effort to recover.